# Do .NET design guidelines suggest returning List<T> over IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: .net, collections

Context: I sent an email to my colleagues telling them about `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` as a way to return empty collections without doing something like `return new List<T>();` I got a reply saying that the downside is that it doesn't expose a specific type:

> That does present a tiny issue.  It’s always good to be as specific as possible about your return type* (so if you’re returning a List<>, make that your return type); that’s because things like Lists and Arrays have extra methods that are useful.  Plus it also can be useful in making performance considerations when using the collection from the calling method.
>
> The trick below unfortunately forces you to return an IEnumerable, which is about as non-specific as possible, right?  :(
>
> * This is actually from the .NET Design Guidelines.  Stated reasons in the guidelines are the same as I’m mentioning here, I believe.

This seemed to be the complete opposite of what I had learned, and try as I might, I couldn't find this exact advice in the design guidelines. I did find one small piece like this:

> **DO** return a subclass of `Collection<T>` or `ReadOnlyConnection<T>` from very commonly used methods and properties.

With a code snippet following, but no more justification at all.

---

So that being said, is this a real and accepted guideline (the way it was described in the first block quote)? Or has it been misinterpreted? All other SO questions I could find have answers preferring `IEnumerable<T>` as the return type. Maybe the original .NET guidelines are just outdated?

Or maybe it's not so clear cut? Are there some tradeoffs to consider? When would it be a good idea to return a more specific type? Is it ever recommended to return a concrete generic type, or only to return a more specific interface like `IList<T>` and `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`?

Comment: I don't have a reference for this, but I've always read that its best to return the most generic type possible. So `IEnumerable<T>` for read only, `ICollection<T>` for editable collections, and `IList<T>` if you need an indexed editable collection.

Comment: I personally always try to return the *least* specific type possible. My methods that return multiple items default to `IEnumerable<T>` unless there's a very good reason to do otherwise (and there very rarely is.) In the cases where I want to make it clear that the collection is an indexable list, I use `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. In general, there's usually no reason to be returning a mutable list to consumers. The .NET guidelines may just be outdated here.

Comment: Do you have a link to the quoted .NET Design Guidelines? I'm guessing is buried in here somewhere: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042

Comment: Note that this is not only about being more generic or more specific, but also about write access. A collection, or a list, allow a modification, while an enumerable only returns the sequence of items. Of course, there are read-only implementations of e.g. `IList<T>`, but you don't see that in the return type. A return type of `IEnumerable<T>` tells users right away: "If you want to modify the list, make a copy." With `IList<T>`, the manual is needed to learn whether it's a copy of or a pointer to the internal list, and whether writing access is allowed or will yield an exception.

Comment: BTW, here's the (collection member) guidelines as of .net 4.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn169389.aspx

Comment: I find this interesting, because I had always read that you should **accept** least generic types, but **return** the most specific type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are reasons for both styles:

1. **Be specific**: You are making a guarantee to callers that you will always return this type. Even when your implementation changes. Can you keep the promise? If yes, be specific to let callers benefit. More derived types have more features.
2. **Be generic**: If you are likely to change the underlying implementation of the method or property in question, you *can't* promise a `List<T>`. Maybe you can promise an `IList<T>` or a custom collection class (which you can change later).

The .NET framework BCL goes with either arrays or custom collection classes. They need to provide a 100% stable API so they need to be careful.

In normal software projects you can change the caller (which the .NET framework guys can't), so you can be more lenient. If you promise too much, and need to change that a year later, you can do that (with some effort).

There is only one thing that is always wrong: Saying that one should *always* do (1) or (2). Always is always wrong.

Here is an example for a case where specificity is clearly the right choice:

```
    public static T[] Slice<T>(this T[] list, int start, int count)
    {
        var result = new T[count];
        Array.Copy(list, start, result, 0, count);
        return result;
    }
```

There is only one reasonable implementation possible, so we can clearly promise that the return type is an array. We will never need to return a list.

On the other hand, a method to return all users from some persistent store might change a lot internally. The data might even be bigger than available memory, which requires streaming. We should probably choose `IEnumerable<User>`.

Comment: Ha, this answer is way more concise than mine. Well said.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with guidelines around decisions like this is that we developers are susceptible to following them blindly, without thinking. I would argue these issues ought to be considered on a case-by-case basis, weighing the advantages and drawbacks of different possible approaches in each case.

With return types, there are really (at least) two ways of looking at it. One philosophy that I see here on Stack Overflow quite often prefers choosing more generic types in order to give *you*—the author of the code—more flexibility down the road. For example, if you write a method that returns an `IList<T>` and the return value is actually a `List<T>`, you reserve the right to later implement your own optimized data structure that implements `IList<T>` and return that in a future version.

A different but in my opinion equally valid alternate philosophy would be that returning more generic types simply makes your library less useful, and so you should return more *specific* types. For instance aggressively returning `IEnumerable<T>` all the time will lead to the scenario where end users of your library are constantly calling `ToArray()`, `ToList()`, etc. I believe this is the basic point your coworker was making when he wrote that "things like Lists and Arrays have extra methods that are useful."

I have sometimes heard the latter approach advocated in words along the lines of "Be specific in what you offer, but generic in what you accept." In other words, take generic *parameters* but offer specific *return values*. Whether you agree with this principle or not, it is easy to at least see the reason behind it.

In any event, as I said each case will differ in the details. For instance in my first example of `IList<T>` versus `List<T>`, you might already be planning to implement a custom data structure and simply haven't written it yet. In this case returning a `List<T>` would probably be a poor choice since you already know the interface will be different in a few weeks or months.

On the other hand, you might have some method that always returns a `T[]` which you choose to expose only as an `IEnumerable<T>` even though the likelihood of this implementation ever changing is very low. In this case opting for the more generic type might be more pleasing to you aesthetically, but it is not likely to actually benefit anyone and in fact deprives the result of a very useful piece of functionality: random access.

So it's always going to be a trade-off, and the best guideline I think you can follow is to always consider your choices and use your judgment to pick the most sensible one for the case in question.

Answer (score 2):

Returning List instead of IEnumerable (or at least IList) essentially violates the [Liskov Sustitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Returning "List" locks you into needing to return that type, and prevents you from refactoring the internals of the method to a potentially more efficient implementation (you promised to return List, but now you want to use "yield" -- oops, can't do it without external code-churn).

In *many* (most?) cases, the predominant requirement of these sorts of methods is to iterate over the results and do something... IEnumerable is exactly appropriate for these uses.

If the user needs to have a mutable set, this is accomplished trivially using "ToList()" or the other extensions on IEnumerable on the other end.

Code that wants you to expose an internal list for direct mutation can be a sign that you are violating encapsulation, too.. Beware. We are finding more and more *Immuability* found in many functional programming languages can be an extremely valuable quality in your code.

Comment: Perhaps "violates" is too strong a word, but my point is that if you return a specific concrete type, with many requirements, it's harder to substitute it out later.

Comment: In many cases, a caller might want to get a count and/or iterate over the collection multiple times.  In which case an IList<T> return type is more useful (avoids the caller needlessly calling ToList() etc).  In any case, the choice has nothing to do with the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @joe From the perspective of implementing the method, this is affected by LSP, from the perspective of the consumer, you could claim this really a violation of ISP, but in either case the API is probably over-specifying what it's returning. What the caller might do with it is up to them, it's trivial to turn an IEnumerable into a collection for just such a purpose, but that puts the onus on the caller to resolve whatever memory issues might result and leaves you open to substitute your implementation if you find a more efficient or appropriate implementation. It is a style choice, though.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it is important to remember that `List<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` have different semantics.

Returning `IEnumerable<T>` just gives the caller a sequence of something that can be enumerated (and possibly turned into a collection). However, there's no guarantee that the sequence has been materialized. So returning `IEnumerable<T>` supports deferred execution. Furthermore, it is implicitly "read only".

Returning `List<T>` means here's a collection. All the work has been done when the method returns. Furthermore, the interface of `List<T>` lets the caller immediately modify the collection as well.

Comment: IList<T> is generally preferred in public APIs over List<T> (e.g. by FxCop).  And IList<T> can reasonably be used to return a readonly list.  I'd only use IEnumerable<T> if I want to indicate to the caller that the API may support deferred execution.

Comment: Users of the C# language should not assume that anything returning IEnumerable<T> will be lazy(or not), the <summary> docs are a much better way to indicate this when it is important or ambiguous.

Comment: I didn't say that they should assume anything. I said returning IEnumerable supports that. Returning a List doesn't.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen Sorry, my comment was in reply to the comment made by Joe. Sorry for the confusion.